# How to handle only scroll on child DOM element instead of body element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the code below for scrolling to the element on a button click event.

Here is the code :

```
this.scrollTo = function(id) {

        var old = $location.hash();
        $location.hash(id);
        $anchorScroll();

        $location.hash(old);
    };
```

With the above code, scroll is working fine. But actually my html page is having two scroll bars one is the default at page level and the other is at sub DOM element level. When the above code executes, its moving both the scroll bars and due to that its not visible correctly.

How can i restrict the default scroll bar and allow only the child/sub scroll bar to handle to scroll event ?

Please look into the below example in Chrome Browser:
[plnkr.co/edit/pXwnjjh3VxCnhTHwd0tJ?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/pXwnjjh3VxCnhTHwd0tJ?p=preview)

Comment: Its not specific and its very common problem, Please check the below link in Chrome browser: (If you observer both the scroll bars will move, but I want only the child scrollbar to move.)

http://plnkr.co/edit/pXwnjjh3VxCnhTHwd0tJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I am facing the problem when I use navigation/top bar. There could be multiple ways to solve the problem by applying CSS styles.

I solved my problem by removing child scroll bar and using the below method:

```
window.scrollTo(0, element.offset().top - 120);
```

Instead of

```
$anchorScroll();
```